# How to save a file from an URL to local in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

According to a [**tutorial**](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/), the code in XmlAppDelegate.m file as below is going to parse the XML file directly from a given URL.

I want to ask is there any way to SAVE the XML file to the local memory FIRST, then process the parsing work accordingly?

Thanks

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml"];
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the bytes as raw bytes and save them to disk before initializing the XML parser with the data:

```
NSData *contents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
BOOL success = [contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:contents];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can always load it into a string:

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

It's best to pass and test an `NSError` object, and you might want to write it to a file (`writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:`).

You can pass the string to `NSXMLParser` with `initWithData:` from an `NSData`:

```
[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: In Cocoa its usually a bad idea to abuse a string for a container of raw bytes. Use `NSData` instead.

Comment: XML is a string, and if the OP wants to process it in any way, he will want it in that format.  The only question is which encoding is correct for XML.

Comment: When getting data from a server and saving that data to a file the fact that the data might contain a string does not matter. Also, the encoding might be known in advance. That's why NSXMLParser takes an `NSData` object, not a string. It's also more efficient: NSString has to parse the contents to check for encoding errors. NSData does not care about its contents.